# How to remove different controller with same parameters from the URL in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem in url structure ... 
I have 3 categories

1. streaming
2. movies
3. serials (dramas)

My Url structure is

```
example.com/stream/CategoryName/Channel Name
example.com/movie/CategoryName/MovieName
example.com/serial/CategoryName/Serial Name
```

I've added in this code in routes.php

```
$route['stream/(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/stream/$1/$2";
$route['movie/(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/movie/$1/$2";
$route['drama/(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/drama/$1/$2";
```

with this structure the website is working good. but client want that the url only contain the category name / Video Name

If i remove stream/movie/drama before /(:any)/(:any) in route then the controller get confused which function to call.

Example what i need

```
example.com/CategoryName/Channel Name
example.com/CategoryName/MovieName
example.com/CategoryName/Serial Name
```

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Uh this is really bad situation.
My solution would look something like this.

```
$route['steam-(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/stream/$1/$2";
$route['movie-(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/movie/$1/$2";
$route['drama-(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/drama/$1/$2";
```

But then u must edit your controller methods to explode first uri by '-' or something like that u can use parsed uri as before in method.
Hope this will help you.